# JFace TableViewer initial vertical scroll position

Tags: jface, tableviewer

I have set up a JFace CheckboxTableViewer in a wizard page with a single sorted column. There are enough entries in the table so that a vertical scrollbar is required.

When I open up the Wizard the majority of the first element in the table has already been scrolled beyond. 
I can only see the bottom of that first table element. 
The second table element is the first that is fully visible.

```java
 private void createCheckboxTable(Composite container) {
    Composite tableContainer = new Composite(container, SWT.NONE);
    TableColumnLayout tableColumnLayout = new TableColumnLayout();
    tableContainer.setLayout(tableColumnLayout);
    GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).applyTo(tableContainer);

    CheckboxTableViewer viewer = CheckboxTableViewer.newCheckList(tableContainer, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION
            | SWT.MULTI);

    ObservableListContentProvider listContentProvider = new ObservableListContentProvider();
    viewer.setContentProvider(listContentProvider);

    Table table = viewer.getTable();
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);// POS 1

    TableViewerColumn tableViewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.LEFT);
    TableColumn column = tableViewerColumn.getColumn();
    tableColumnLayout.setColumnData(column, new ColumnWeightData(1, ColumnWeightData.MINIMUM_WIDTH, false));
    column.setText("Column");
    tableViewerColumn.setLabelProvider(new DependencyInfoFileNameColumnLabelProvider());

    TableSortConfigurator.newConfigurator(viewer, new Action() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            viewer.refresh();
        }
    }).add(column, new DependencyInfoNameComparator()).initialize(column, SWT.UP).configure(); //POS 2

}
```

As a test, and before the sorting occurs, I entered the following line at POS 1 above:

```java
table.setSelection(0);
```

After opening the wizard again I saw that the selected element is the last which is visible at the bottom of the table. So it seems that this is the reason for the unusual initial vertical position in the table.

When I remove the `code table.setSelection(0);` from POS 1 and add it to POS 2 something strange happens. The first element in the table is selected as I expected, but I still observe the same initial vertical scrolling.

In other words, the first element of the table is correctly selected, but is only partially visible.

Does anyone know what is going on here? Alternatively is there some method I have missed which returns the view to the top of the table?

Thanks